# show third level ul menu with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problems with creating a dropdown menu with jQuery.

This code shows the sub menus on hover but I couldn't get the sub sub menu to work too

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li").has(".sub").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".sub").toggle();
  });
});
```

Here's the JS code

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVmabP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lose the `sub-sub` class and use the immediate descendant selector to help you:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li>11111
    <ul class="sub">
      <li>2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>11111
    <ul class="sub">
      <li>2</li>
      <li>22222
        <ul class="sub">
          <li>3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li").has("> .sub").hover(function() {
    $(this).find("> .sub").stop().slideToggle();
  });
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbvbLr)

Note that this would work for unlimited nested `.sub`s.

Comment: brailliant !! Thanks so much

Comment: @mamak24 Glad to have helped!